# In Django how can I run a custom clean function on fixture data during import and validation?

Tags: database, django, validation, fixture

In a ModelForm I can write a `clean_<field_name>` member function to automatically validate and clean up data entered by a user, but what can I do about dirty json or csv files (fixtures) during a `manage.py loaddata`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixtures loaded with `loaddata` are assumed to contain clean data that doen't need validation (usually as an inverse operation to a prior `dumpdata`), so the short answer is that loaddata isn't the approach you want if you need to clean your inputs.

However, you probably can use some of the underpinnings of loaddata while implementing your custom data cleaning code--I'm sure you can easily script something using the Django [serialization libs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) to read your existing data files them in and the save the resulting objects normally after the data has been cleaned up.

Comment: Yea, my data was generated with dumpdata. The model and validation rules just changed before the loaddata. Will just build a custom loaddata filter, like you suggest. Seems I'm the only SO user that munges their fixtures.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that is a tricky case then.  It does sounds like you're on to the best route, though.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no validation hooks for loaddata, that I can find, and you can't just override the deserializer to make loaddata do validation/clean_data your way, you have to copy all the loaddata command and force it to use your deserializer or just work in serial fixture land to adjust the data to fit the model... like you suggest, but simplejson is best for that for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case others want to do something similar, I defined a model method to do the cleaning (so it can be called from ModelForms)

```
MAX_ZIPCODE_DIGITS = 9
MIN_ZIPCODE_DIGITS = 5

def clean_zip_code(self, s=None):
    #s = str(s or self.zip_code)
    if not s: return None
    s = re.sub("\D","",s)
    if len(s)>self.MAX_ZIPCODE_DIGITS: 
        s = s[:self.MAX_ZIPCODE_DIGITS]
    if len(s) in (self.MIN_ZIPCODE_DIGITS-1,self.MAX_ZIPCODE_DIGITS-1):
        s = '0'+s # FIXME: deal with other intermediate lengths
    if len(s)>=self.MAX_ZIPCODE_DIGITS:
        s = s[:self.MIN_ZIPCODE_DIGITS]+'-'+s[self.MIN_ZIPCODE_DIGITS:] 
    return s
```

Then wrote a standalone python script to clean up my legacy json files using any `clean_` methods found among the models.

```
import os, json

def clean_json(app = 'XYZapp', model='Entity', fields='zip_code', cleaner_prefix='clean_'):
    # Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = app+".settings"
    settings = __import__(app+'.settings').settings
    models   = __import__(app+'.models').models

    fpath    = os.path.join( settings.SITE_PROJECT_PATH, 'fixtures', model+'.json')
    if isinstance(fields,(str,unicode)):
        fields = [fields]
    Ns = []
    for field in fields:
        try:
            instance = getattr(models,model)()
        except AttributeError:
            print 'No model named %s could be found'%(model,)
            continue
        try:
            cleaner = getattr(instance, cleaner_prefix+field)
        except AttributeError:
            print 'No cleaner method named %s.%s could be found'%(model,cleaner_prefix+field)
            continue
        print 'Cleaning %s using %s.%s...'%(fpath,model,cleaner.__name__)
        fin = open(fpath,'r')
        if fin:
            l = json.load(fin)
            before = len(l)
            cleans = 0
            for i in range(len(l)):
                if 'fields' in l[i] and field in l[i]['fields']:
                    l[i]['fields'][field]=cleaner(l[i]['fields'][field]) # cleaner returns None to delete records
                    cleans += 1
            fin.close()
            after = len(l)
            assert after>.5*before
            Ns += [(before, after,cleans)]
            print 'Writing %d/%d (new/old) records after %d cleanups...'%Ns[-1]
            with open(fpath,'w') as fout:
                fout.write(json.dumps(l,indent=2,sort_keys=True))
    return Ns

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clean_json()
```